# Why is string.contains() returning false?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have the following string: `\\\?\hid#vid_04d8pid_003f#62edf110800000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}` stored in a string variable (from a function call) called `devPathName`

and the following defined:  `const string myDevice = @"vid_04d8pid_003f";`

but the following code always evaluates to false:

```
Boolean test = true;

test = devPathName.Contains(myDevice);

statusLabel.Text += "\n\tThe value of test: " + test.ToString();
```

Comment: It returns true on my machine. You might want to provide more info about the context of that code and how you're testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you've already checked for letter "O" vs digit "0" and similar things, I'd suggest that the string you're seeing in the string variable `devPathName` is being encoded for display and isn't quite what you think it is.

For example, if the string contains the character `\x000d` (`Control-M`), the Visual Studio debugger will display this as `\r` when you inspect the value of the string.

Or, for another example, if the string contains the sequence 3504 (three-five-zero-four) but you instead search for `35O4` (three-five-oh-four) then you'll not find a match.

(Depending on your font, you may not be able to see differences between some characters. Compare "0O1lB8S5" with "`0O1lB8S5`" in different fonts to see what I mean.)

Comment: Hhmmm.... do you mean I need to convert it using UnicodeEncoding? I actually retrieve that string from an IntPtr ( `devPathName = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pdevPathName);`) but could you please explain what you mean?
Thanks

Comment: @dark-star1 - updated my answer with a clarification, hope this is clearer.

Comment: You and Pat seem to have hit the nail on the head. attempting to use the Path.* threw up exceptions showing that there's a '\r' and '\n' in there somewhere. I'm guessing this is at the beginning of the returned string. Is there a way to side step this or do I have to copy the string, modify and then test it for my substring?

Comment: One good rule of thumb is to always sanity check input that comes from outside your application, whether directly entered by a user or not. As a first step, you could use Trim() to remove leading and training whitespace - but if it was my code, I'd go further to be rigourous.

Comment: You'll have to forgive my sloppiness. I'm learning C# and Visual studio 2008 express environment at the same time. I've always avoided coding on windows for a good reason. Anyways I found out that the string is constructed thus: an '&' is used to aggregate each piece of informationin the string. though this character is not displayed. it was this little thing that was throwing me off.

Comment: @dark-star1 - Were you perhaps displaying the string in a Label instead of viewing a variable in the debugger? Standard Windows behavior for "&" in labels (and in buttons and a few other places) is to mark the accelerator character for use with the Alt-key. 

For example, you give a label the caption "&Name", which displays with the "N" underlined, and you can use Alt-N to select the Label (or the control associated with the Label).

Answer (score 7):

When I stick your code into C#, the compiler doesn't like the "\h" part of your long string. It says, "unrecognized escape sequence". Could that be your problem?

Oh, and if I put a "@" before the long string, the contains() method returns true.

HTH,

-Dan

Answer (score 0):

This returns true for me as well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            const string myDevice = @"vid_04d8pid_003f";
            string devPathName = @"\\\?\hid#vid_04d8pid_003f#62edf110800000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}";
            Boolean test =devPathName.Contains(myDevice);
            MessageBox.Show("\n\tThe value of test: " + test.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I guess I would put a breakpoint in and make sure that devPathName isnt being changed on you and that the value is what you expect.

Comment: devPathName is returned thus: devPathName = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pdevPathName); and 
pdevPathName: pdevPathName = new IntPtr(deviceDetailDataBuffer.ToInt32() + 4); 
I have tried all the following: 
1) Path.GetFullPath() => returns and exception saying there're control characters (\r\n), but removing the first 4 characters get's rid of this problem. 
2) removing the 1st 8 characters such that the string starts with my required substring. Still returns false.

Comment: What type is deviceDetailDataBuffer? Is it a decimal?  Where does the value come from? You could create a function to check for only letters/digits and punctuation to remove any escape charactors.  See Char.IsLetterOrDigit and Char.IsPunctuation.

Comment: deviceDetailDataBuffer is an IntPtr that is returned by a function, and the built in string.Replace() functions can apparently remove escape characters.

Comment: You might want to try string path_name = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(deviceDetailDataBuffer);

Answer (score 0):

What's evaluating to false, your test variable or part of the display in statusLabel.text? Are you sure the display isn't something like this:

```
The value of test: false
The value of test: false
The value of test: false
The value of test: false
The value of test: true
The value of test: false
```

and maybe you're only looking at the first line of that string?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape the long string before parsing it via .Contains()

Put an at-symbol (@) at the start of the string, as demonstrated in several of the previous answers and it should evaluate perfectly.

When stepping into .Contains, the initial string, in your case

```
\\\?\hid#vid_04d8pid_003f#62edf110800000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}"
```

contains non-escaped characters and causes .Contains to terminate before it completes the comparison.

Comment: unfortunately there's no way I can escape it that I know of as this string is supposed to be the path to a device returned from a setupapi* function. Do you know of a way/function that would llow me to filter out control characters such as '\r' and '\n'?

Comment: I think your only option in that case is to save it as a local variable and do whatever you need to before you pass it to .Contains

If the function you're passing it to doesn't have the ability to return it as a "safe" string.

Comment: I finally figured it out. I ws watching the debugger when I noticed that the returned string that describes the device had a '&' between each part was decribing the device. So although the string being displayed is: \\\?\hid#vid_04d8pid_003f#62edf110800000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}. The actual string in the buffer is: \\\?\hid#vid_04d8&pid_003f#6&2edf1108&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}

Comment: Bevan picked that one. // Credit where credit is due. ;-)
Glad you found it and it's working for you.